# what is zipF factor and why is its value 0.89?

Tags: statistics, computer-science, probability

Can someone tell me where I can use it ? Does it have something to do with weights and distribution ?? I am trying to study a code which uses zipf value to be 0.89 with no mention of as to why ?

Comment: Math question, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's the exponent parameter for a distribution following [Zipf's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law).